# How do I get Jackson library to use my default initialized value when deserializing null value?

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I have this JSON input:

```
{
    "teachers": null,
    "students": [],
    "janitors": ["J1", "J2"]
}
```

It will be mapped to this `School` object.

```
public class School {
    
    // Child JSON arrays reflecting JSON input
    private List<String> teachers = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> students = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> janitors = new ArrayList<>();
    
    // Getters and Setters
    public List<String> getTeachers() {
        return teachers;
    }
    public void setTeachers(List<String> teachers) {
        this.teachers = teachers;
    }

    public List<String> getStudents() {
        return students;
    }
    public void setStudents(List<String> students) {
        this.students = students;
    }

    public List<String> getJanitors() {
        return janitors;
    }
    public void setJanitors(List<String> janitors) {
        this.janitors = janitors;
    }
}
```

This is my mapper configuration so far:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

After the Jackson library deserializes the JSON input, I get that School.teachers = null despite initializing it as an array. My reason for initializing these arrays is to avoid unnecessary null checks.

How can I get the Jackson deserializer to ignore null values or ignore null nodes that it cannot map to?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` at your class like.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class School {
    
    // Child JSON arrays reflecting JSON input
    private List<String> teachers = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> students = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> janitors = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

You can also use it at the field level; in case you want some fields to be nullable.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;

public class School {

    // Child JSON arrays reflecting JSON input
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    private List<String> teachers = new ArrayList<>();

    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    private List<String> students = new ArrayList<>();
    
    private List<String> janitors = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

So in the above scenario if janitors is null it would be displayed as null.

Comment: It will work for serialization, not for deserialization